# How do I enable MongoDB's safe mode on an entire connection/server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a Rails application and I need to have MongoDB's safe mode enabled all the time for one of the servers.

**How to enable safe mode for all requests?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.WRITE_CONCERN.html

```
@con = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017, :safe => {:w => 2})
@db  = @con['test']
@collection = @db['foo']
@collection.save({:name => 'foo'})

@collection.save({:name => 'bar'}, :safe => false)
```